# Foreign Key Constraints not imported through Visual Studio Data Source Wizard

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, foreign-keys, constraints, wizard

I have a remote MySql database. I have used the Visual Studio Data Source Configuration Wizard to link to it in my app. It imports all fields and tables fine and connectivity is also fine. However, the foreign key constraints do not seem to be imported. Here is one of the MySql database foreign key setup:

[image]

Note the relationship for GameID. Now here's the corresponding relationship in the VS dataset visualiser:

[image]

Note that it gets imported as "Relationship Only" and not "Foreign Key Constraint" (or "both"). I've tested the local dataset function: there is no delete cascade happening. I can't find any properties anywhere to change.

How does one get VS to automatically import the foreign key constraints? Changing each relationship individually is not an option as any future database schema changes (and consequential re-run of the wizard) would overwrite these.